# Указание totalvalue для Mytarget в Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В скрипте Mytarget для динамического ремаркетинга необходимо указать параметры:

```
type: 'itemView',
productid: 'ID',
pagetype: 'product',
list: '1',
totalvalue: '???'
```

Что прописать в тотал, если взять в расчёт цену товара, _regular_price?

Спасибо за советы!

Comment: а где вы взяли скрипт, скиньте ссылку

Comment: Это в личном кабинете самого таргета.